# Code that parses a file containing league played game history, outputting a json to import into a database

Tags: javascript, node.js

So the code simply parses a text file that stores some game history for a gaming league. It's part of a discord.js app - for not particular reason.

The code is ugly and could definitely use some tips on what I should change. It does work, I need to make a few additions to handle some data that shows up on the rarely in the logs. By no means do I declare myself knowledgeable with node.js or even javascript.

I realize the loops should probably be put into some sort of function. Feedback would be appreciated.

Snippet of the game data:

```
    Game 352
    Game Type: Diplo
    1: @czozp#8908 
    1: @MrGtheFox#6511 
    3: @Anlcankose#6985 
    4: @Alan#3070 
    5: @Amadeus#3194 
    6: @iartur#8087 


    **ENDGAMEGame 353
    Game Type: Diplo
    1: @Negi#1116 
    2: @Simard#8647 
    3: @ #1337 
    4: @Shadow_link291#7162 Quit
    5: @Bullerfnis#0968 
    6: @ #1737 


    **ENDGAMEGame 354
    Game Type: Diplo
    1: @lolitsjack#6921 
    2: @jaximus#1438 
    3: @iartur#8087 
    4: @xavier#9632 
    5: @groove#8337 
    6: @Amadeus#3194 


    **ENDGAMEGame 355
    Game Type: Diplo
    1: @owlelg6#5745 
    2: @TomBraider#6882 
    3: @wewt#9184 
    4: @-=SunZ=- aslevuli#6629 
    5: @Cybrick#9042 Quit
    6: @Buttercup#0358 Quit


    **ENDGAMEGame 356
    Game Type: Diplo
    1: @Dolla Bill#4821 Faith Victory
    2: @Falisanda#5010 
    3: @Datapunkt#2179 
    4: @groove#8337 
    5: @Simard#8647 Quit
    6: @JollyJoker#0127 Quit


    **ENDGAMEGame 357
    Game Type: Diplo
    1: @czozp#8908 16101
    2: @MrGtheFox#6511 74
    3: @Svelander#4629 090 
    4: @Maho974#2701 
    5: @Taigz#8748 Quit
    5: @Alan#3070 Quit


    **ENDGAMEGame 358
    Game Type: Teamer
    CivLeague Modded
    1st Team:
        @frnch#9718 
        @© • Song Adieu#6276 
    2nd Team:
        @The green pickle#3423 
        @General (Desert Fox)#0453 


    **ENDGAMEGame 359
    Game Type: Diplo
    1: @白甲#0681 
    2: @Tyree#1158 
    3: @Justifier#7095 
    4: @Merc#6962 
    5: @iartur#8087 
    6: @xavier#9632 


    **ENDGAMEGame 360
    Game Type: Diplo
    1: @MrGtheFox#6511 
    2: @Morgoth#4793 
    3: @WineTime#8812 
    4: @bclemas03#2604 
    5: @Jessomadic#2897 
    6: @mike#3166 
    7: @ed2001#9873 
    8: @TomBraider#6882 Nullified


    **ENDGAMEGame 361
    Game Type: Diplo
    1: @BlairIsMyMind?#0429 
    2: @NewbieOne#7348 
    3: @YOYO4230#7170 
    4: @mike#3166 
    5: @Lauro#5943 
    6: @Gabi#5215 


    **ENDGAMEGame 362
    Game Type: Diplo
    1: @Justifier#7095 
    2: @lolohcrap#8475 
    3: @Xer#3460 
    4: @thunderbolt#6037 
    5: @Tyree#1158 
    6: @lolitsjack#6921 


    **ENDGAMEGame 363
    Game Type: Diplo
    1: @Bullerfnis#0968 
    1: @Tiri#8430 
    3: @allfalldown#3126 
    4: @groove#8337 
    5: @Compello#5533 
    6: @Lauro#5943 


    **ENDGAMEGame 364
    Game Type: Teamer
    CivLeague Modded
    1st Team:
        @The green pickle#3423 
        @© • Song Adieu#6276 
    2nd Team:
        @★HG★ Mason   (NotMason)#8215 
        @InfernoArcine#1189 


    **ENDGAMEGame 365
    Game Type: Diplo
    1: @TranWang#4036 
    2: @JJ#8864 
    3: @czozp#8908 
    4: @onfire369#1882 
    5: @General (Desert Fox)#0453 
    6: @Anikulapo#7642 


    **ENDGAMEGame 366
    Game Type: Diplo
    1: @lacuscryne#1882 
    2: @白甲#0681 
    2: @GaelicWarrior#2034 
    4: @urlik#3458 
    5: @ed2001#9873 
    6: @Reckless#7826 


    **ENDGAME
```

here is the actual code:

```
client.on("message", message => {
        if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix) || message.author.bot)
            return;

        const args = message.content.slice(config.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
        const command = args.shift();
        switch (command) {
            case("parseGames"):
            {
                function readModuleFile(path, callback) {
                    try {
                        var filename = require.resolve(path);
                        fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', callback);
                    } catch (e) {
                        callback(e);
                    }
                }

                var games = {};
                games.Matches = [];
                games.Matches.Match = [];
                var start = /([Game\s?][0-9]{0,3},?([0-9]{3})?[\s\S]*?\*\*ENDGAME)/gm;
                var m;
                readModuleFile('./GameHistory.txt', function (err, words) {
                    var i = 0;
                    do {
                        m = start.exec(words);
                        if (m) {
                            rGameId = /Game\s?(([0-9]{0,3}),?([0-9]{3})?)/gi;
                            rGameType = /Game Type:\s?(\w+)/gi;
                            rPlayer = /(\d):\s?@(.*?)#([0-9]{0,4})/gi;
                            rTeamPlayer = /@(.*?)#([0-9]{0,4})\s+(\w+)/gi;
                            rSubs = /(\d+)Subbed.*?[\s\S]*?(?=.*?[\d+]:|\*\*ENDGAME)/gmi;
                            rTeam = /(\d+).*?Team:.*?[\s\S]*?(?=.*?[\d+].*?Team:|\*\*ENDGAME)/gmi;
                            game_id = rGameId.exec(m[1]);
                            game_type = rGameType.exec(m[1]);
                            if (game_id) {
                                if(game_type){
                                    games.Matches.push({
                                        id: game_id[1].replace(/\,/g, ''),
                                        type: game_type[1]
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                            rIsTeam = /(teamer|teamers|team)/gi;
                            is_team = rIsTeam.exec(game_type[1]);
                            if(is_team){
                                var t = 0;
                                games.Matches[i].Team = [];
                                do {
                                    team = rTeam.exec(m[1]);
                                    if(team){
                                        games.Matches[i].Team.push({
                                           team_id: team[1],
                                           position: team[1],
                                           Players: []
                                        });
                                        do {
                                            player = rTeamPlayer.exec(team[0]);
                                            if (player) {
                                                games.Matches[i].Team[t].Players.push({
                                                    username: player[1],
                                                    descriminator: player[2],
                                                    Modifiers: []
                                                });
                                            }
                                        } while (player); 

                                    }
                                    t++;
                                } while (team); 

                            }else{
                                games.Matches[i].Players = [];
                                do {
                                    player = rPlayer.exec(m[1]);
                                    if (player) {
                                        games.Matches[i].Players.push({
                                            position: player[1],
                                            username: player[2],
                                            descriminator: player[3]
                                        });
                                    }
                                } while (player);                            
                            }
                        i++;
                        }
                    } while (m);
                    fs.writeFile("./test.json", JSON.stringify(games), function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                            return console.log(err);
                        }

                    });

                });
                return;
            }
        }

    });
```

From what I foresee the code would end up being something like:

```
    var Matches = {};


    function parseMatches()
    { 
        do{
            let matches = regxResult;
            //...
            if(x){
                //should I call parseMatch here or after creating/init/populating the matches object?
                // this question would be for all the functions essentially
             match = parseMatch();
             // push match to Matches
            }
        } while(matches);
    }

    function parseMatch()
    {
        do{        
        let match = regxResult;
            //...
            if(match){
                if(xIsTeams){
                    match = {
                        id: match_id,
                        Teams: []
                    };
                 teams = parseTeams();
                 //push teams to match.
                 //Object.push(match);

                }else if(!xIsTeams){ //This would be wrong way of checking if the object 
                    players = parsePlayers();
                 //push players to match.
                }
            }
        } while(match);    
    }

    function parseTeams()
    {
        do{        
        let teams = regxResult;
            //...
            if(teams){

                players = parsePlayers(); // return array of players for current team.
                team = {
                    id: team_id,
                    Players: [players] 
                };

            }
        } while(teams);    
    }

    function parsePlayers()
    {
        do{        
        let players = regxResult;
            //...
            if(players){
             player = {
                 id: player_id,
                 username: username,
                 position: position,
                 Quests: []
             };
            }
        } while(players); 

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, when you declare a variable without the `var`, `const` or `let` keywords you are declaring them in a global scope, so the variables like `rGameType, rGameType` would 'leak' and affect others scopes.

As you are using ES6, try to use `let` instead of `var` to have more control over scopes inside your function, you can see why [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

Besides that, you are correct, its a good practice to separate logic in functions, so its become more clear what is happening.

You can start refactoring this code, create a function named something like `loadMatches`, using the code below.

```
      rGameId = /Game\s?(([0-9]{0,3}),?([0-9]{3})?)/gi;
      rGameType = /Game Type:\s?(\w+)/gi;
      rPlayer = /(\d):\s?@(.*?)#([0-9]{0,4})/gi;
      rTeamPlayer = /@(.*?)#([0-9]{0,4})\s+(\w+)/gi;
      rSubs = /(\d+)Subbed.*?[\s\S]*?(?=.*?[\d+]:|\*\*ENDGAME)/gmi;
      rTeam = /(\d+).*?Team:.*?[\s\S]*?(?=.*?[\d+].*?Team:|\*\*ENDGAME)/gmi;
      game_id = rGameId.exec(m[1]);
      game_type = rGameType.exec(m[1]);
      if (game_id) {
           if(game_type){
               games.Matches.push({
                  id: game_id[1].replace(/\,/g, ''),
                  type: game_type[1]
               });
            }
      }
```

Using your code as functions instead of plain blocks of code will make easier it to debug and improve over time.

Comment: if I use async/await does the function need to return a value?

Comment: Nope; I think you can pass an object as a param and change it without problems.